# How to display custom taxonomies in posts?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Almost all themes display categories (with its permalink) by default. I am looking for similar type of code to add in my theme. From where can I get it?
To create custom taxonomies, I'm using [More Taxonomies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-taxonomies/) plugin.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way to list terms of custom taxonomy and display them would be to use

```
 <?php get_the_term_list( $id, $taxonomy, $before, $sep, $after ) ?>
```

For example in the loop, my custom taxonomy is 'jobs' list as li

```
 <ul><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'jobs', '<li class="jobs_item">', ', ', '</li>' ) ?></ul>
```

Comment: I was able to display the items this way:
<code><ul><?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'jobs', '<li class="types_item">', '</li><li class="jobs_item">', '' ) ?></ul></code>

Comment: Great answer. I tried loads of different ways but this work perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

None of the code on this page worked, but the example from the wordpress site did:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'people', 'People: ', ', ', '' ); ?>
```

I got it from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list

Hope it helps other lost souls who would like to display the current post taxonomies :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. it worked for me. i have a taxonomy named 'stores', and i wanted to display 2 taxonmies from it.

```
<?php
    $taxonomy = 'stores';
    $args1=array(
        'include'=> array(12,30)
        );

    $terms = get_terms('stores',$args1 );
    echo '<ul>';


    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        //Always check if it's an error before continuing. get_term_link() can be finicky sometimes
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'stores' );
        if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
            continue;
        //We successfully got a link. Print it out.


        echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```